# Enviar JavaScript por email

Tags: c#, email

Eu tenho um código em C# que manda emails com HTML, até aí ok, o problema é que eu não consigo mandar scripts(JS). Sim, entendo porque,deve ser motivos de segurança. Mas não tem como `burlar` ou fazer de outra forma? -- Sem nenhuma intenção maliciosa. Meu código:

```
using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
        {
            mail.From = new MailAddress("xxx@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add("xxx@gmail.com");
            mail.Subject = "xxx";
            mail.Body = @"<script>SCRIPT aqui.</script>";
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

            using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
            {
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxx@gmail.com", "xxx");
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(mail);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Como vc perguntou se isso não pode ser feito de outra forma, qual seria a função do script?

Comment: @dvd Apenas mostrar um alerta. Eu sei que posso exibir a mensagem no HTML,mas eu queria exebir um `alert` em JS, só para ver se iria funcionar.

Comment: Então, os servidores de e-mail, por exemplo Gmail, Hotmail e afins, por segurança não deixam nada disso executar, não há como burlar, a única forma, vejo eu, seria utilizar algum receptor de e-mail que não dependam desses serviços de e-mail, aí sim, pois estes utilizam algum tipo de stripHtml ao receber a mensagem, ou seja, a sua mensagem chega em qualquer leitor de terceiros ou outros, já sem estes scripts! Acredito ser uma demanda em vão, encontre alternativas!

Comment: @isaque qual é o seu objetivo com isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você sempre pode enviar blocos de script junto HTML do seu e-mail, o problema é que ele será removido no servidor ou não será executado. A grande maioria dos clientes de e-mail vão remover ou desabilitar a execução de scripts por questões de segurança, independente se o seu código é malicioso ou não.

Antigamente, início dos anos 2000, isso ainda era possível. Inclusive alguns clientes como o Outlook e Exchange executavam até VBScript e isso era bem arriscado no ambiente windows.

Porém, dependendo do que você espera e acha que precisa do JavaScript para alcançar, pode ser realizado de outras formas. Como por exemplo a confirmação de leitura, que pode ser feita incluindo um parâmetro na url de carregamento de uma imagem e monitorar isso no log do servidor (desde que o usuário habilite e aceite exibir as imagens).